Azure ADB2C Custom Policy Social IdP - Updated Facebook Client Id and Secret
I have updated the custom policy with new Facebook Client Id and Secret. When user logs in with Facebook account that is already registered in ADB2C tenant, there is an error I got that "Email already exists".
Is there any way to fix/update Custom Policy, to avoid Facebook users trying to generate kind of new user, but at the same time on my tenant?
This question is pretty similar to this one Change facebook application on custom policies azure b2c. But I don't follow the provided answer.
Here is my part of Extension where the error message shown, it is pretty standard from the Starter Pack:
<ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Social accounts</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!-- force unique email address - Collect, validate and return the email address as output claim.           So, next orchestration step will persist the email to the directory            into otherMails attribute -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-SocialEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Continue</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!--force unique email address - This technical profile tries to find a local account with provided email address-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingLocalAccountEmail-NoError">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tempObjectId" PartnerClaimType="objectId" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <!-- force unique email address - This technical profile tries to find a social account with provided email address-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingSocialEmail-NoError">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.socialEmailAddress" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tempObjectId" PartnerClaimType="objectId" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <!-- force unique email address - this technical profile displays the message to the user-->
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-UniqueUserMessage">
          <DisplayName>Email unique validation</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
            <!-- hide the continue and cancel buttons -->
            <Item Key="setting.showContinueButton">false</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.showCancelButton">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <!--InputClaimsTransformations>             <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateTheUniqueEmailErrorMessage" />           </InputClaimsTransformations-->
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="uniqueMailUserMessage" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Show the paragraph claim with the message to the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="uniqueMailUserMessage" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

I'm almost new to the Policy customizations. I've updated Google Application Client Id, it works fine after replacement. So that, I was assuming that same workflow will work for the Facebook IdP.

Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve? Local and social accounts are different; the only way to combine them is to link them.

The only thing I need is to have single Facebook profile, and ability to login already existing users from Facebook, after changing Facebook App client credentials


The only thing I need is to have single Facebook profile, and ability to login already existing users from Facebook, after changing Facebook App client credentials

If you look at your user identities, you'll see something like this:
"identities": [
  {
    "signInType": "userName",
    "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "johnsmith"
  },
  {
    "signInType": "emailAddress",
    "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "jsmith@yahoo.com"
  },
  {
    "signInType": "federated",
    "issuer": "facebook.com",
    "issuerAssignedId": "5eecb0cd"
  }
]

Look at the old Facebook entries before you made the change. Compare this to the new ones. It sounds like they are different?
If so, update the old ones to look like the new ones.
